# SpriteKit Cosine and Integers

Tags: swift, trigonometry

```
var xAxisImpulse = 0
var yAxisImpulse = 0
if angleToShoot < 90 && angleToShoot > 0 {
xAxisImpulse = cos(angleToShoot)*45 //cos is in radians
}
```

There is an error at the cos(). It says that because the angleToShoot var is an int, it can not be executed. How can I change this so that this can work?

Comment: CGFloat(45) or Double(45)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use CGFloat or Double as that this the data type used by the cos function.

```
var angleToShoot : CGFloat = 0.0

var xAxisImpulse : CGFloat = 0.0
var yAxisImpulse : CGFloat = 0.0
if angleToShoot < 90 && angleToShoot > 0 {
   xAxisImpulse = cos(angleToShoot)*45 //cos is in radians
}
```